# Enter some greek words in latin text with latin keyboard

Tags: greek

I need to enter a few greek words (i.e., with greek letters) in a text set in latin letters, using a latin keyboard. I wonder whether my choice of the bgreek package is the recommended way nowadays, because although most of it works, it seems that a few lowercase letters are not available; in particular there is only one variant of kappa (the one that resembles a latin x but not the one that looks more like a latin k), one of theta (the one that looks like 0 with a horizontal bar is missing), and one of phi (the one that more resembles the uppercase phi is missing). I don't actually know greek, so I wonder why that is and if the two variants of these letters are interchangeable or, if not, how I can get these letters, because the source I am copying the text from uses these missing variants.

Comment: If you are copying text from a source anyway, why not just use Unicode in your TeX file and copy & paste as it is?

Comment: While I have small Latin and less Greek, I *can* confirm that the variant forms of the letters are, in fact, equivalent. Also, in polytonic greek, the accents ˜ and ˆ are the same accent (generally called "circumflex" even when it has the tilde shape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, the different shapes you describe are just type variants and not linguistically significant. That said, you might prefer to use the `lgreek` package which has the original Silvio Levy typeforms loaded. The form of θ in particular is different although κ and φ still have the same shape.

[image]